# React native running on the device error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

my react native app wont run when the device is connected on my laptop.. but the app will run successfully on genymotion. I dont know what the problem is. Can anyone suggest me some solutions to this problem. Thank you

This is problem i get on my device, but no problem when running on genymotion[image]

Answer (score 2):

check this out, probably you not set up your dev server

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html#configure-your-app-to-connect-to-the-local-dev-server-via-wi-fi

1. Make sure your laptop and your phone are on the same Wi-Fi network.
2. Open your React Native app on your device. You can do this the same way you'd open any other app.
3. You'll see a red screen with an error. This is OK. The following steps will fix that.
4. Open the Developer menu by shaking the device or running `adb shell input keyevent 82` from the command line.
5. Go to `Dev Settings`.
6. Go to `Debug server host for device`.
7. Type in your machine's IP address and the port of the local dev server (e.g. 10.0.1.1:8081). On Mac, you can find the IP address in System Preferences / Network. On Windows, open the command prompt and type `ipconfig` to find your machine's IP address (more info).
8. Go back to the Developer menu and select `Reload JS`.

Answer (score 0):

what your android version device ?

the first think should you do after your plugg in your device via usb, check that your device is properly connecting to ADB by running `adb devices`.

1. Open your cmd find your adb directory path example : C:\Users\your_name\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
2. Run `$ adb devices` and see list devices attached. U must have one devices only one device connected at a time.

After check devices are connected and then run your app `$ react-native run-android`.
If your android version 5.0 lollipop running the following in your cmd `$ adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` and you can reload your aplication, but if still error you can run via wi-fi, [you can use this tutorial if you run via wi-fi,](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html)  but you'll first need to install the app on your device using a USB cable.